# Room/SQLite returning two different results in one query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, conditional-aggregation

So I've got the following queries:

```
//returns min max value my odomoter field must have
@Query("SELECT MAX(odometer) FROM MaintenanceRecord WHERE vehicleId = :maintenanceVehicleId AND " +
        "maintenanceTs < :dateAsLong")
Maybe<Float> getMinAllowedOdometer(long dateAsLong, int maintenanceVehicleId);


//returns the max value my odometer field is allowed to have 
@Query("SELECT MIN(odometer) FROM MaintenanceRecord WHERE vehicleId = :maintenanceVehicleId AND " +
        "CAST(strftime('%s',DATE(maintenanceTs/1000,'unixepoch'))  AS  integer) > " +
        "CAST(strftime('%s',DATE(:dateAsLong/1000,'unixepoch')) AS integer)")
Maybe<Float> getMaxAllowedOdometer(long dateAsLong,int maintenanceVehicleId);
```

One function returns the min value the `odometer` column must have, and the other query returns the max value the `odometer` column  is allowed to have.

The issue is that **BOTH** functions are executed after each other since I need to subscribe to both functions. That's bad practice, In my honest opinion.

Can I put these two queries in one query and return `Maybe<Float, Float>` as a result?
My other solution would be running these functions synchronously; instead of `Maybe<Float>,` I would directly return `Float.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get both columns in a single query:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN maintenanceTs < :dateAsLong THEN odometer END) AS max_odometer,
       MIN(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%s', DATE(maintenanceTs / 1000, 'unixepoch')) AS INTEGER) > CAST(strftime('%s', DATE(:dateAsLong / 1000,'unixepoch')) AS INTEGER) THEN odometer END) AS min_odometer
FROM MaintenanceRecord 
WHERE vehicleId = :maintenanceVehicleId;
```